# Would you help me to get an idea to do next after String w1 = scanner.nextLine(); to check for the occurrence of the words

Tags: java

A file called “getwordinfo.txt” should reside in your project directory that should contain some of the words that have been found in the input files. Read in each of the words from this file (maybe using a simple Scanner object), and then output the following to the console window:
The word itself

The list of occurrences of that word, or, if the word never occurred, simply output “Not found”
The total number of occurrences of the word, and the usage frequency of the word (as a percentage) relative to all word occurrences in the input files
 //

```
File fileInTheFolder = new File(f, docname);
fileInTheFolder.createNewFile();

File infile = new File("input.txt");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(infile);
String w1 = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far ? What do you need to do with each word ? Don't expect people to do your homework without some effort on your side :)

Comment: Have a good read of the [JavaDoc for Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), experiment with some of the methods to try and get closer to a solution, then update the code in your post with what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do (read: what I would probably do as a first approach) is to create a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) to hold the data in and then, using your reader insert the data into the map one by one.
A Map, for example:

```
 HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

works by having two fields, a key and a value. In your case the key is the word you want to count instances of and the value is the counter value.
Once you have your map you can begin inserting into it.
For example, as seen here:

```
for (String a : args) {
    Integer count = m.get(a);
    m.put(a, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
}
```

What we do is:

Check if a has already been seen.
If it has been seen then we add to the counter ( + 1) otherwise we set the initial counter value to 1.

So if you could take your line and parse it into words, go through the words and insert them into the map you will have your answer.